# False Position method in Octave

Tags: octave

I have wrote a code to find roots using the false position method. It gives the correct answer but it always takes the maximum number of iterations possible. I noticed that my upper bound is never  being changed, meaning my error will always remain high. Any ideas why?

```
   fprintf('Be sure to mark all multiplication with a *\n\n\n');
 str=input('Give an equation in x with right hand side=0: ', 's');
   %User types in their equation
 f=inline(str);
   %Converts from string to function 
 xl=input('Choose the lower bound for the guess interval: ');
 xh=input('Choose the upper bound for the guess interval: ');
   %Input the upper and lower bounds to initial guess
while(f(xl)*f(xh)) > 0 
   fprintf('There is no root in this interval\n')
   %Prompt user the interval is incorrect
 xl=input('Choose the lower bound for the guess interval: ');
 xh=input('Choose the upper bound for the guess interval: ');
   %Input a new upper and lower bound for the initial guess
endwhile
if f(xl) == 0 
   fprintf('There is a root at the lower bound\n')
    %Inform the user their lower bound is located on a root
elseif f(xh) == 0 
   fprintf('There is a root at the upper bound\n')
    %Inform the user their upper bound is located on a root
endif
 tol=input('What would you like your lowest error to be: ');
    %User inputs their desired error value
for i=1:1000 %Limit total iterations to 1000
  xm=((xl*f(xh)-xh*f(xl))/(f(xh)-f(xl))) %Define center value based on method
     if f(xl)*f(xm) < 0 
         xh=xm
     else
         xl=xm
     endif
    %Check which half the root is located in
if abs((xh-xl)/2) < tol
  break
endif
    %Stop loop once error is acceptable
endfor
fprintf('The root: %f\nThe number of iterations: %d\n',xl,i);
    %Display the root and number of iterations
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions on [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. Your code clearly is Octave, and doesn't run as-is in MATLAB. Please keep the tags separate, unless you're explicitly asking about differences between the two languages.

Comment: can you provide an example set of inputs?  when you step through the code, are you expecting it to go into the `if f(xl)*f(xm)<0` block and it does not? can you create a set of test inputs where you would expect that to happen to see if the correct code path is followed? i suspect something about your xm = () block is always creating values below  the midpoint.  have you checked the values of xm to see if they should indeed be going into the xh=xm block?

Comment: I have done this, and the  xm=((xl*f(xh)-xh*f(xl))/(f(xh)-f(xl))) %Define center value based on method line seems to be the problem! The inputs are not working properly here. Thank you :)